# Cavity resonator modeling with Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions, vector-calculus, electromagnetics

I am attempting to determine eigenfrequencies and the corresponding electric field distribution in a rectangular cavity resonator with perfectly conducting walls. In the simplest case of a rectangular cavity resonator, the problem is typically solved using the following Mathematica code:

```
Ω = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {25, 2, 4}];   
NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[{Ex[x, y, z], Ey[x, y, z], Ez[x, y, z]}, {x, y, z}], 
  DirichletCondition[Ex[x, y, z] == 0, 
   y == 0 || y == 2 || z == 0 || z == 4], 
  DirichletCondition[Ey[x, y, z] == 0, 
   x == 0 || x == 25 || z == 0 || z == 4], 
  DirichletCondition[Ez[x, y, z] == 0, 
   x == 0 || x == 25 || y == 0 || y == 2]}, {Ex, Ey, Ez}, {x, y, z} ∈ Ω, 10]
```

I am interested in specifying boundary conditions, particularly the orthogonality of the electric field to the boundaries, in a way that allows solving the problem for arbitrary cavity geometries. The challenge is that `DirichletCondition[]` does not currently support the cross-coupling of dependent variables. It is not possible to directly state

```
DirichletCondition[Cross[n,{Ex[x, y, z], Ey[x, y, z], Ez[x, y, z]}]==0, True]
```

where `n` is a vector field orthogonal to the region boundary.

I would appreciate guidance on alternative methods or approaches to express the boundary conditions, considering the limitation mentioned above.

Comment: The code is correct; I'm addressing an electrodynamic problem, not electrostatic. Therefore, the Laplacian is applied to the electric field (refer to, for example, "Electrodynamics of Continuous Media: Volume 8" by Landau). While the code functions for a cuboid region, how should I adjust the form of the boundary conditions to enable the code to work for arbitrary geometries?

Comment: It would become a problem for arbitrary cavity geometries. To specify tangential or normal components automatically is complicated for complex geometries. From my experience, it would be only possible to specify these types of Dirichlet conditions to geometries which ara parallel to one of the axes.

Comment: The limitation comes from that Mathematica uses Lagrange elements and not Curl/Edge/Vector elements. These types of elements could solve your problem of specifying the type of boundaries you want. For now, simple geometries, like your rectangle or 2D geometries are possible.